# Django parallel tests not creating database tables

Tags: django, postgresql, django-tests

I'm trying to run Django tests in parallel using the following command:

```
python manage.py test myproject.myapp.tests --parallel=4 --keepdb
```

However, I get errors like the following:

```
...
File "/home/daniel/Envs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_user" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "accounts_user" ("password", "last_login", "is_s...
                    ^
```

which means that the tables are not being created in the Postgres test DBs. As required, I have created DBs named `test_myproject_1`, `test_myproject_2` and so on, and upon inspection in pgAdmin, I see the tables are indeed not there. My assumption was that the tables are created automatically when the tests are run.

I don't get such  errors when running the tests on a single thread, in other words, when I don't use the `--parallel` option or when I use `--parallel=1`, which uses the `test_myproject` database. Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem could be?

Comment: I think `--keepdb` might be causing this error. `--keepdb` will not destroy the database after the tests nor will create the database if it already exists. It applies the unapplied migrations if there is any. I believe there might be some unapplied migrations to the test database but somehow the database is corrupted so it can not apply the migration. Can you try dropping all relevant databases and try running without `--keepdb`.

Comment: Without the `--keepdb` I get an error `permission denied to create database`. But if the `--keepdb` was the issue, why would it be able to apply the migrations for a single DB and not all the others?

Comment: Same problem here without keep-db. Django 1.11. Tried with postgres and sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies within the use of both `--parallel` and `--keepdb`, where the alternative test databases won't be migrated to the current state. Running `--parallel` without `--keepdb` will force a refresh of the database schemas in the test databases.

(If you were unable to run without `--keepdb` because of `permission denied to create database` you need to check if your database user has the correct permissions.)

There is [an open issue #26822](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26822) and a [partial patch](https://github.com/django/django/pull/7551) aiming to fix this, but there hasn't been any activity for a while. Also see [the discussion on Django-developers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/Y7EGWoC82ag/discussion).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Hopefully the issue will be resolved in the near future. It would be great not having to wait 4+ minutes for my tests to run locally on a single thread.